# Inaccessible logs: Security. The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched

Tags: c#, ios, iis, asp.net-web-api

**I am assuming it has something to do with my app pool/IIS but why is this error only being thrown while in Production?**

**To Start**- I have read every related question about this topic on SO.

I cannot reproduce this error in my Dev and/or Test environments. I have sent hundreds of POST requests using postman(DEV), I have also used my iOS application pointing to my Test Environment and sent thousands of requests and I am still in the same boat.

**About my Project:** I am using WebAPI and my application is running on iOS10 written in swift. I only receive this error occasionally and cannot reproduce it on command. I am wondering if anyone else has run into this issue and if so, what were the steps you took to take care of this problem?

```
Error #1
The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched. 
To create the source, you need permission to read all event logs to make 
sure that the new source name is unique. Inaccessible logs: Security.
```

**Note:** This error is not causing me to lose any data when I receive it, all records are still being committed to my database. So it is not a huge issue since I only get the error 1 out of about 100 times a new record is submitted. But curiosity is killing me and wanted to see if anyone had any suggestions.

Comment: No answer(s), dangit! Having the same problem.